# What's wrong in this code?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, dev-c++

In Case 1 , do not check any errors, but in Case 2 , 3, 4 and 5, sends me an error that some variables have already been declared

```
//Autor 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main ()
{
    char nom[25];
    int Co;
    int P;
    int op;
    printf("\t\t La Nacional");
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("\t\t Menu\n\n");
    printf(" 1.Arrachera\n 2.Costillas\n 3.Alitas\n 4.Cabrito\n 5.Camarones\n");
    printf("\n\n");
    printf(" Nombre de cliente:");
    scanf("%s",nom);
    printf("\n Elija una opcion:");
    scanf("%d", &op);
    printf("\n\n");
    switch(op)
    {
    case 1:
        printf(" Arrachera\n");
        printf("\n\n");
        printf(" El combo incluye");
        printf("\n Ensalada\n Tortillas\n Salchicha\n Refresco");
        printf("\n Precio: $250");
        printf("\n\n");
        printf(" Cantidad de combos:");
        scanf("%d", &Co);
        long A=(Co*250);
        printf("\n\n");
        printf(" Su subtotal es: %ld" ,A);
        long Tt= (A*.16)+ A;
        printf("\n\n");
        printf(" Su total es: %ld" ,Tt);
        printf("\n\n");
        printf(" Con cuanto va a pagar?");
        scanf("%d" ,P);
        long F=(Tt-P);
        printf("\n\n");
        printf(" Su cambio es: %ld", F);
        break;

    case 2:
        printf("El combo de Costillas incluye:");
        printf("\nEnsalada\nTortillas\n Salsa BBQ\nRefresco");
        printf("\nPrecio: $200");
        printf("\n\n");
        printf(" Cantidad de combos:");
        scanf("%d", &Co);
        long A=(Co*200);
        printf("\n\n");
        printf(" Su subtotal es: %ld" ,A);
        long Tt= (A*.16)+ A;
        printf("\n\n");
        printf(" Su total es: %ld" ,Tt);
        printf("\n\n");
        printf(" Con cuanto va a pagar?");
        scanf("%d" ,P);
        long F=(Tt-P);
        printf("\n\n");
        printf(" Su cambio es: %ld", F)
        break;

    case 3:
        printf("El combo de Alitas incluye:");
        printf("\nEnsalada\nSalsa\nAderezo\nRefresco");
        printf("\nPrecio: $150");
        printf("\n\n");
        printf(" Cantidad de combos:");
        scanf("%d", &Co);
        long A=(Co*150);
        printf("\n\n");
        printf(" Su subtotal es: %ld" ,A);
        long Tt= (A*.16)+ A;
        printf("\n\n");
        printf(" Su total es: %ld" ,Tt);
        printf("\n\n");
        printf(" Con cuanto va a pagar?");
        scanf("%d" ,P);
        long F=(Tt-P);
        printf("\n\n");
        printf(" Su cambio es: %ld", F)
        break;

    case 4:
        printf("El combo de Cabrito incluye:");
        printf("\nEnsalada\nPapa\nQueso\nCebolla\nRefresco");
        printf("\nPrecio: $210");
        printf("\n\n");
        printf(" Cantidad de combos:");
        scanf("%d", &Co);
        long A=(Co*210);
        printf("\n\n");
        printf(" Su subtotal es: %ld" ,A);
        long Tt= (A*.16)+ A;
        printf("\n\n");
        printf(" Su total es: %ld" ,Tt);
        printf("\n\n");
        printf(" Con cuanto va a pagar?");
        scanf("%d" ,P);
        long F=(Tt-P);
        printf("\n\n");
        printf(" Su cambio es: %ld", F)
        break;

    case 5:
        printf("El combo de Camarones Empanizados incluye:");
        printf("\nEnsalada\nGalletas\nPapas\nArroz\nRefresco");
        printf("\nPrecio: $200");
        printf("\n\n");
        printf(" Cantidad de combos:");
        scanf("%d", &Co);
        long A=(Co*200);
        printf("\n\n");
        printf(" Su subtotal es: %ld" ,A);
        long Tt= (A*.16)+ A;
        printf("\n\n");
        printf(" Su total es: %ld" ,Tt);
        printf("\n\n");
        printf(" Con cuanto va a pagar?");
        scanf("%d" ,P);
        long F=(Tt-P);
        printf("\n\n");
        printf(" Su cambio es: %ld", F)
        break;

    default:
        printf("La opcion no existe");
        break;
    }
    printf("\n");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

In Case 1 , do not check any errors, but in Case 2 , 3, 4 and 5, sends me an error that some variables have already been declared

Comment: You are re-defining the variables in each `case` statement.  You should move the declaration above the `switch` and just set the value for each `case`..

Comment: Alternately, you could put statements for each case in a separate block.  But by all means, indent your code properly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not declare the variables inside the `case`'s without using braces, and besides it's not necessary, because you can declare them before the `switch`.

Also, `scanf("%d", P);` is the problem, the `"%d"` specifier for `scanf()` expects a `int` pointer, so it should be

```
scanf("%d", &P);
```

and you need to check the return value of that, which [should be `1`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html).

The link will help you understand better how to use `scanf()`.

Comment: That's *a* problem, but it's not the one being asked about.